# jQuery Get TypeError: a is null with code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery 2.2.4 and a small script and the script is making jQuery give me the following error:

```
TypeError: a is null


...th>0},fa.contains=function(a,b){return(a.ownerDocument||a)!==n&&m(a),t(a,b)},fa....
```

Console is pointing at "a.ownerDocument"

Now this is the code that's responsible for making the error happen:

```
$(function() {
        $('[class*="inc:"]').each(function() {
            var match = /inc:(\S+)/.exec(this.className || '');
            match && $(this).inc(unescape(match[1]));
        });
    });
```

My index.html code is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript" src="inc.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <p class="inc:footer.html">This text will be replaced
    with footer.html</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is the full inc.js:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.inc = function(url, transform, post, t) {
        return this.length && url ? this.each(function() {
            t = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                success: function(txt, jqXHR, textStatus) {
                    t.html($.isFunction(transform) ? transform(txt, url) : txt);
                    $.isFunction(post) && post(url, jqXHR, textStatus);
                }
            });
        }) : this;
    };

    $(function() {
        $('[class*="inc:"]').each(function() {
            var match = /inc:(\S+)/.exec(this.className || '');
            match && $(this).inc(unescape(match[1]));
        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: This is a violent abuse of the `class` attribute. If it's not for CSS selectors, don't use `class`! Instead, use something more logical, eg. `<p data-include="footer.html">`. jQuery can access this with `$('[data-include]').each(function() {var elem = $(this), src = elem.data("include"); elem.inc(src);});`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan McCrossan, I've added the whole inc.js to the question..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use instead

```
  $(function() {
    $('[class*="inc:"]').each(function() {
        var match = /inc:(\S+)/.exec(this.className || '');
        if(typeOf(match[1]) != "undefined")
          match && $(this).inc(unescape(match[1]));
    });
  });
```